# How can a service with PrivateTmp=true access a unix socket in the /tmp directory (e.g. to submit Torque jobs from PHP running in Apache)

Tags: systemd, apache-httpd, unix-sockets, torque

We have a webserver that performs scientific calculations submitted by users. The calculations can be long-running, so we use The **[Torque](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/6-0-2/adminGuide/help.htm)** resource manager (aka pbs_server) to distribute/schedule them on a handful of compute nodes.  Torque makes use of a unix domain socket in the `/tmp` directory for communication but the http server (and processes forked from it) can't access the true `/tmp` directory, so to those processes, the socket appears to be missing, resulting in an error.

The Details:

- The webserver is running Apache, which runs as a service with the systemd property `PrivateTmp=true` set. This casuses the service to have its own `/tmp` directory unrelated to the "true" root /tmp.
- The jobs are actually submitted from PHP (running in the Apache process). PHP makes a system call to `qsub`, which is a Torque command to submit a job. Because `qsub` is called from PHP, it inherits the "fake" `/tmp` directory from Apache.
- `qsub` internally attempts to connect to the unix socket located at `/tmp/trqauthd-unix`.  But since it doesn't see the real /tmp directory, it fails with the following error:   `Error in connection to trqauthd (15137)-[could not connect to unix
  socket /tmp/trqauthd-unix: 2]`

The only solution I could achieve was to edit the httpd.service file under systemd and change `PrivateTmp` to false. This DID fix the problem. But I'd rather not do this because (I assume) PrivateTmp was set to true for good reason.

What I want to know is whether there is any way to have the socket created in a different location or to somehow make a link to the socket that could be used from within Apache (and its forked processes).

Creating a link to the socket is trivial, but it doesn't solve the problem because I don't know of any way to configure `qsub` to look for the socket in a different location.

Note that the socket is created by the `trqauthd` service (a Torque program that performs user authorization for running jobs). The documentation for trqauthd mentions (in an obscure note) that the location of the socket can be configured, but there is no indication in any of the documentation about how that can be achieved (and more importantly, how to let qsub and other commands know about the new location).

Thanks for any suggestions that might help me find a way to submit jobs to Torque from PHP *without* disabling PrivateTmp for Apache.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In 2013, [`trqauthd` stopped using IP sockets](https://github.com/adaptivecomputing/torque/commit/33a123e154d278c1714ae8ab2a8dac6a196dadf4) and switched to a Unix domain socket in the server's home directory.

Later that same year, [`trqauthd` switched from the home directory to `/tmp`](https://github.com/adaptivecomputing/torque/commit/7d2e4391e3c3fb5bd5d6da8a4c87bc21c96c80ef).

As you can see, the only option that Adaptive Computing has given to you for altering `/tmp/trqauthd-unix` is to re-compile the programs from source, changing the `--with-trqauthd-sock-dir` build configuration option to denote somewhere other than `/tmp`.  (`/run/trqauthd` perhaps?)

Comment: That's what I figured. So basically, the only options for getting this to work are (1) set `PrivateTmp=false` in `httpd.service` or (2) Recompile Torque from source. Option 1 potentially adds security vulnerabilities and Option 2 makes maintenance a problem, because pre-built binary packages are no longer an option, and each subsequent sys-admin has to make special note of this or spend hours trying to find out why /tmp/trqauth-unix is unaccessible to PHP despite all the standard unix permissions being right.

Comment: I'll add this just as a comment, but a third option might be to write small daemon that would simply watch a folder for job scripts and submit them to qsub when present. That way, PHP could just worry about writing the script and `qsub` would be invoked by the daemon (which would NOT be running under the Apache process and hence would not be using a private `/tmp` folder.  But I'm not sure that this doesn't add more security holes than simply turning `PrivateTmp=false` for Apache.